# Jasmine spy document.execCommand is not called

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I write a test like this

```
describe('execCommand', function () {
    it('should call document.execCommand', function () {
        spyOn(document, 'execCommand').and.callThrough();
        expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foreColor', false, 'red');
        document.execCommand('foreColor', false, 'red');
    });
});
```

But it fail `Expected spy execCommand to have been called with [ 'foreColor', false, 'red' ] but it was never called.` and I don't know why?

Please help.

Note: I run it using `grunt-contrib-jasmine` `0.9.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jasmine's `expect` function is an assertion at that time rather than an assertion that will be run at the end of the `it` block, switch the order to see it working:

```js
describe('execCommand', function () {
  it('should call document.execCommand', function () {
    spyOn(document, 'execCommand').and.callThrough();
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, 'red');
    expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foreColor', false, 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```